# The value of "browser" object in Before hook is undefined in wdio cucumberjs

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, cucumberjs, wdio, wdio-v6

I am using `cucumberjs`, `@wdio/cucumber-framework(version:7.16.13)`, `wdio(version: 7.16.13)` along with javascript.

Due to some issue I have to define `before` hook of wdio in my step definition file(`mystepdefinition.js`):

**mystepdefinition.js:**

```
    import { Before } from '@wdio/cucumber-framework';
    ...
    Before( function(capabilities, specs, browser){
        console.log("*******************************************");      
        console.log("capabilities:"+JSON.stringify(capabilities));
        console.log("specs:"+specs);
        console.log("browser:"+browser);
        
        console.log("*******************************************");      
    });

other step definitions...
```

**Output:**

capabilities: *very long json object containing all details of feature file and its scenarios*

specs:

```
(error, result) => {
                if (value_checker_1.doesHaveValue(error)) {
                     reject(error);
                 }
                 else {
                     resolve(result);
                 }
             }
```

browser:**undefined**

Here it is printing value of browser as **undefined**. It is printing some value of capabilities and specs though these values are also weird.

But my question here is why value for browser is undefined? **Actually my main motive here is to get the name of scenario currently running.** Can anybody tell me the solution?

Edit: Please note that we define hooks generally in wdio.conf.js file where hook name is `before`. But when we define hook in step definition by importing them from `@wdio/cucumber-framework` then its name is `Before`. Note the first letter b. If I use the `before` hook in `wdio.conf.js` then it prints proper values of all 3 parameters but not when I use `Before` hook in step definition file.